# Stack overflow error in assembly

Tags: assembly, 64-bit

I am trying to write code that takes input from the user and displays the factorial, in assembly x64. Every time I run the code it gives me Unhandled exception at 0x00007FF64B910B11 in finalProjectAssembly.exe: 0xC00000FD: Stack overflow (parameters: 0x0000000000000001, 0x00000019F1603FF8)., but I do not understand how the stack has overflowed. What am I missing?

```
INCLUDELIB libcmt.lib
INCLUDELIB legacy_stdio_definitions.lib

EXTERN printf:PROC
EXTERN scanf:PROC

.DATA
prompt  BYTE    "Enter a number: ", 0
inFmt   BYTE     "%d", 0
prompt3 BYTE    "The factorial is: %d",10,0
cont    QWORD   ?
disp    BYTE    "You Entered %d", 10,0
num     QWORD   ?
num2    REAL8   1.5

.CODE
main PROC C
sub     rsp, 24
lea     rcx, prompt          
call    printf
lea     rdx, num             
lea     rcx, inFmt           
call    scanf
push    num

mov     rdx,num              
lea     rcx, disp            
call    printf
call    factorial
mov     rdx, rax
lea     rcx, prompt3
call    printf

lea     rcx, prompt2
call    printf
lea     rdx, cont
lea     rcx, inFmt
call    scanf

add     rsp,24             
mov     rax,0
ret
main ENDP

factorial PROC
push    rbp
mov     rbp,rsp
mov     rax, [rbp + 16]
cmp     rax, 1
jle     quit
dec     rax 
push    rax
call    factorial
mov     rbx, [rbp+16]
imul    rbx

quit:
mov     rsp, rbp
pop     rbp
ret
factorial ENDP
```

Comment: While on _SO_, Stack Overflow would happen inevitably!

Comment: At what point does the failure occur? Before or after "You Entered nn"?

Comment: The failure occurs at push rbp in the factorial. So after "You Entered"

Comment: Have you used a debugger to look at the contents of `num`?  Is `%d` the proper scanf format string for a `QWORD`?  It might print correctly (since your printf also uses %d), but that doesn't mean there isn't some 0xccccc at the top of the 64bit value.

Comment: I'd be surprised the code you posted assembles given that `prompt2` hasn't been defined.

Comment: The 64-bit Windows Calling convention requires allocating a full 32 bytes on the stack before a function call is made. This is called the shadow space. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235286.aspx

Comment: Additionally, I'd move the `push num` down just before the call to factorial.  You don't want it to get confused for an argument to printf.  Between these two things, you're probably getting some HUGE number in rax at the start of factorial.  The recursion thus eventually runs out of stack space.

Answer (score 0):

If you call foreign functions (`printf`,`scanf`) you **must** obey their calling conventions. The appropriate [Microsoft x64 software convention](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/stack-allocation) determines that you have to reserve at leat space for four qwords (=32 bytes) in the stack before calling the function. The function can freely use that "shadow space". Furthermore, ESP have to be aligned to an address divisible by 16.

Change

```
sub     rsp, 24
```

to

```
sub     rsp, 32
and     spl, -16        ; Align to 16
```

You don't need the `add     rsp,24` at the end of the `main` function. The correct prolog (`push rbp; mov rsp, rbp`) and the correct epilog (`leave`) will be inserted automatically by the assembler ML64.

The shadow space has to be straight in front of the function's return address pushed by the `call` instruction. Move the `push num` close to `call factorial` and don't forget to clean up the stack:

```
push    num
call    factorial
add     rsp, 8
```

Don't forget to clean up the stack:

```
push    rax
call    factorial
add     rsp, 8
```

I didn't check the format specifier `%d` as recommended by David Wohlferd. The program basically works with the changes above.

Comment: You can see the problem with num by initializing it to 0cccccccccccccccch instead of '?'.  I believe the correct string for MS CRT for both scanf and printf is "%I64d".

Comment: @DavidWohlferd: Yes, I see now - not only truncation but conversion to SDWORD. Newer versions of the MS CRT also support the standard `ll`: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hf4y5e3w.aspx. It's more reasonable to use `%llu` or `%I64u`. The result can become very big but not negative.

Comment: ...except you want the factorial of a negative number.

Comment: `%I64d` was consistent with OP's design, so I thought it might be easier for OP to understand.  But you are right: factorials of negative numbers are undefined, so %I64u (or the more portable %llu) would be better.  The tricky thing about this problem is that the printf would look right (since like scanf it is using 32bits), but the code could still fail because it was actually using all 64 bits in the calculation.